# CSS Background-Image zoom out

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I’m using bootstrap carousel slider with 4 images, the last 2 images fit perfectly, the first 2 do not, they get cut off at the top, the first two images are 4000 x 3000 and the last two are 4000 x 2000. Is there away to zoom out of a background image? I am using background-size: cover and my first two images get cut off, does anyone have any suggestions on what I should do?

```
.fill { width: 100%;  height: 100%; background-position: center; background-size: cover; }


<header id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
                <!-- Indicators -->
                <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
                </ol>

                <!-- Wrapper for Slides -->
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="item active">
                        <!-- Set the first background image using inline CSS below. -->
                        <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('/Images/banner-images/slider-1.jpg?v=4789372489');"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <!-- Set the second background image using inline CSS below. -->
                        <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('/Images/banner-images/slider-2.jpg?v=4789372489');"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <!-- Set the third background image using inline CSS below. -->
                        <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('/Images/banner-images/slider-3.jpg?v=4789372489');"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <!-- Set the third background image using inline CSS below. -->
                        <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('/Images/banner-images/slider-4.jpg?v=4789372489');"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Controls -->
                <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
                    <span class="icon-prev"></span>
                </a>
                <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
                    <span class="icon-next"></span>
                </a>

            </header>



.carousel {
    height: 600px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {

    .carousel {
        height: 75vh;
    }
}
```

Comment: With `background-size: cover` there are not any way to set the size of background. By the way if you need to have a full view of the image you can use `background-size: contain` but in this way the image will not cover all the carousel slide area. So you need to choose if have a part of image cutted  and cover all the slide space, or view the entire picture but not cover all the slide space.

Comment: You could use `background-size: 100% 100%` to occupy the entire area.

Comment: I tried background-size: 100% 100% but that stretch the image.

Comment: `contain` will leave blank spaces, `cover` will cut something, and `100% 100% ` will stretch. You can't satisfy everything with pictures out of proportion. (It doesn't even make sense that it would be possible)

Answer (score -1):

Try aspect ratio. It may help with the proportion.